# GCM Checking for Delivery Failure when time_to_live = 0

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to determine if the delivery of a message failed when `time_to_live = 0`?

According to the GCM reference, messages that have `time_to_live = 0` are attempted to be delivered immediately, but are discarded on failure, rather than saved for future delivery.

I was wondering if there was a way to determine if the message was discarded because of a failed send attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement error handling. See [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#error_reference).

Also, you can recover non-collapsible messages which **are stored** by `onMessagesDeleted.listener` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#messages_deleted_event).

Hope this answers your question.